# How to get PyCuda SourceModule to compile multiple source files containing device code?

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I'm trying to use some LAPACKE functions inside a CUDA kernel to solve small systems of linear equations. I have a main source file that contains the kernel function I want to call. Inside that kernel function I want to call the LAPACKE function `LAPACKE_dgesv()`, which is defined in a different source file.

In my main source file I have included the header file `lapacke.h` which contains the declaration for `LAPACKE_dgesv()`. In addition I have edited `lapacke.h` to prepend `__device__` to the function declaration of `LAPACKE_dgesv()`.

I added the directory of the source file that contains the definition of `LAPACKE_dgesv()` to the `include_dirs` argument of the SourceModule call in my Python code. However when I run the code I get this error:

```
ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function 'LAPACKE_dgesv'
```

My guess is that the source file containing the definition of `LAPACKE_dgesv()` is not being compiled.

Is there a way to get PyCuda to compile multiple source files that contain device code? It seems that there would need to be a way for PyCuda to run the CUDA compiler with the `--relocatable-device-code=true` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this with `SourceModule`.

There is an experimental [`DynamicSourceModule`](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/blob/master/pycuda/compiler.py#L416) which has been added to the Master branch very recently and which probably can do what you want, although it isn't well documented and I have never used it. Otherwise, you can always statically compile and device link the code to a cubin file yourself outside of PyCUDA and just load the resulting device code via the standard APIs.

Comment: So if I manually create a cubin file outside of PyCuda could I then load it into my Python code using the `module_from_file` PyCuda function?

Comment: Yes.  You also have the advantage of being able to a priori inspect the contents of the cubin to get symbol names in the case where you have C++ linkage in the device code